# ASP.Net on Linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono

I want to use ASP.Net on Linux because of license problems and costs. Can you compare its performance?

We coded a few asp.net applications and work well on windows server, can we migrate to linux + apache + mono without any changing? Framework version is 2.0.

Comment: If you need Licenses you could try http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/ they help out start ups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in this question:

[Performance of ASP.NET in Mono(Linux) vs IIS(Window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929210/performance-of-asp-net-in-monolinux-vs-iiswindow)

And here's the FAQ from mono on ASP.NET:

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked the port is not fully complete.  Depending on how familiar you are with the language you may find that something is missing.  Then you will deal with performance!

Answer (score 0):

Well to run .Net on Linux you'll need [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).
I don't really know about it's performance as I am not a big fan of .Net.
Also please reformat your question into something more formal.
'Coz' doesn't really make you look good.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into this doc:

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET

so you can check if all the stuff that you use in your app is implemented or not.

You can speed up things if you use mod_mono+apache.

Answer (score -1):

I think you would need to give us more details. ASP.NET does not natively run on Linux.  The only thing that I know of that can do this is [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130). Given these details, and true answer could probably be provided